# Manipulate Solve for initial condition

Tags: equation-solving, manipulate

I have a series of $n$ coefficients with parameters $r$ and $b$ that sum up to one. But there i also the initial condition value $c1$ that i required to obtain this normalization. I want to find this $c1$ for each $r$ and $b$ value plug it back in to my table and plot those values. I used manipulate as follows:

```
     ClearAll["Global`"];
     clc;
     a = 1/(1 - b*r);
     c = (1 - r - b*r (1 - r*b))/((1 - b*r) (b - 1)*r);

     Manipulate[
      solveC1 = 
       Solve[Total[Table[N[1/(c1*n!)*((-1)^n*FactorialPower[a, n]) + 
             1/n!*Sum[(k - n)*Binomial[n, k]*(-1)^(n - k)*FactorialPower[a, n - k], {k,                            1, n}]], {n, 0, 20}]] == 1, c1];
      Print[c1 /. solveC1], {r, 0.001, 1}, {b, 0.001, 1}]
```

Please bear with me and let me know of any suggestion you have as I'm a beginner in Mathematica.

Thanks.

Comment: Your brackets and parenthesis don't balance

Comment: sorry I had simplified the equation and in that process missed a parenthesis.

Comment: I do not understand your code at all. You have 2 control variables `r` and `b`, yet they do not appear anywhere in the Manipulate expression.  Before jumping to using Manipulate, you should first test your code as standalone, on a cell by its own, to make sure it even works. You can enter some values for the parameters. Then when it is working, you can use Manipulate to automate things.

Comment: @Nasser $FactorialPower[a, n]$ the $a=\frac{1}{1-br}$ and that's how this depends on b and r.

Comment: But this code is not in the Manipulate expression. You should put all control variables dependent code inside Manipulate.

Comment: Thanks @Nasser. I thought inside or out it would use that expression for $a$. I assumed it was just a matter of _Local_ vs _Global variable_ sort of thing and can't harm if it's out of the manipulate brackets.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: It makes big difference. look at this: `Manipulate[x, {{x, 0, "x="}, 0, 1, .1}]` which works, move the slider and it updates. Now move `x` outside, as in `x = 1; y = x; Manipulate[y, {{x, 0, "x="}, 0, 1, .1}]` now move the slider, and nothing happens. no update. The control variable has to appear inside the Manipulate expression to be tracked.

Comment: Thanks a lot it makes sense. I'm glad I shared my thought.

Comment: Plus I wasn't sure how to define them inside the Manipulate I assumed something like _initialization_ is the only way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Manipulate[
       solveC1 = Quiet@Solve[(Total[t[b, r]]) == 1, c1];
       ListLinePlot[t[b, r] /. solveC1, PlotRange -> All],
 {r, 0.001, 1},
 {b, 0.001, 1}, 
 Initialization :> {a[b_, r_] := 1/(1 - b*r), 
                    t[b_, r_] := Table[N@1/(c1*n!)*((-1)^n*FactorialPower[a[b, r], n]) + 
                                  1/n!*Sum[(k - n)*Binomial[n, k]*(-1)^(n - k)*
                                  FactorialPower[a[b, r], n - k], {k, 1, n}], {n, 0, 20}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is working thanks. My question is that how would you plug this back into the equation to plot different entries in the Table? Using _Manipulate_ and _DiscretePlot_?